# What does __uuidof(someVar) do?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, uuid

I found some code which is meant to call `__uuidof(IMyInterface)` but actually calls `__uuidof(pIMyInterface)` where `pIMyInterface` is a pointer of type `IMyInterface`. How does `__uuidof` behave when called on a value rather than a type?

e.g. `int x=123; __uuidof(x)` is this equivalent to `__uuidof(int)` or `__uuidof(123)`

Comment: [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zaah6a61.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ;)

Comment: Yes but I don't know what that means - it says its valid but not what is actually returned. Is it the GUID of the variable type or its contents or something else for instance?

Comment: Could you please also describe what __uuidof() will return?

Answer (score 9):

`__uuid` is a *keyword*, not a function.  It is not "called", it is directly parsed by the compiler.  Which of course has no trouble recognizing that the operand is a variable.  And it knows the type of the variable so has no trouble looking up the `__declspec(uuid)` attribute for the type.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuidof-operator):

```
__uuidof (
   expression 
)
```

> The expression can be a type name, pointer, reference, or array of that type, a template specialized on these types, **or a variable of these types**. The argument is valid as long as the compiler can use it to find the attached GUID.

Comment: But what is the "attached GUID" for "a variable of these types"? Does it just use the variable's type e.g. `int x=123; __uuidof(x)` is equivalent to `__uuidof(int)`?

Comment: It's always the GUID of "that type", which must be a struct or class type with an attached UUID. `uuidof(int)` is invalid, as int has no UUID.